# Vue component styles never disappear

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Why do `Vue Single File Component` inline styles that get appended to `header` once mounted stay there forever? Even when the component is destroyed its styles never disappear.

I need component styles to get removed from header once it is destroyed

**Here's the example of what I mean:**

[Simple playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/61jn989rqn)

1. `Component1` is created and the styles from it append to header

[image]

2. `Component2` is created, `Component1` is removed respectively. Styles from the second component append to `<header>`, but styles from the first one are also still there
   [image]

Comment: May I ask why you want the `component styles to get removed from header once it is destroyed`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an answer from vuejs developer:
https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6218#issuecomment-318000174

Basically in production environment all your styles should be placed in one static file using [css extraction](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#Extracting-Component-CSS) for better CSS minification and caching. Therefore no styles are removed after adding.